# How do you access an Android SDK DB via DB Visualizer?

Tags: android

I am trying to use DB Visualizer to look at the contents of a SQLite DB.
I can look at it via the adb, but the functionality is somewhat limited.
I'm running the SDK under Eclipse Galileo version 3.5).
Even though DB Visualizer doesn't officially support SQLite, it does work.
I downloaded the jdbc driver.
The problem I'm having is setting up the connection URL: 
it needs the location on my PC for the .db file, which is actually in the
C:\Documents and Settings....android\avd\avdName\ directory.
When the app is running, I can use the Eclipse Window / Show view / File explorer
to see the /data/data/packageName/databases/mydb.db name,
but the .db file doesn't acually exist in the PC file space.
Has anyone had success using DB Visualizer to look at an Android SDK SQlite DB?

Comment: Assuming you're using the emulator or a rooted phone, just copy the database to your local hard drive via adb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you see the above image you will see a option for saving the `.db` file.(Left hand image)

Now save the .db file in your local drive of your PC.

Now use [sqllite-manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) plug-in for firefox to view the .db file.

Comment: By the way: I'm using DB Visualizer instead of the firefox plugin. It works fine that way: it gives me a .db file name on my PC so I can then use the URL:     jdbc:sqlite:C:\mydatabase.db                                       C:\mydatabase.db is what I specified when I used the SDK File Explorer to 'pull a file from the device' using the left hand image.